# SQL CASE SELECT INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

HI Guys i have a question...

I have a table

```
Name    Country         Date
abc     Singapore       1/1/1111
cde     Korea           1/1/1111
fgh     Korea           1/1/1111
ijk     Singapore       1/1/1111
mno     Singapore       1/1/1111
pqr     Singapore       2/1/1111
stuv    Korea           2/1/1111
wxy     Korea           2/1/1111
z       Korea           2/1/1111
```

I want it to come out like this

```
Country     Date(1/1/1111    Date2 (2/1/1111
Singapore   3                1
Korea       2                3
```

Note. Date and Date 2 either one or both can be temporary columns

I tried

```
SELECT  Country, Count(Country) AS Quantity , 'Date1' As Expr1 
FROM Reg
WHERE Date= #6/16/2014#
GROUP BY Country;
```

But as for the part i tried casing But it dosnt seems to work...

```
SELECT Reg.Date, Reg.Country, Reg.Date1 
CASE Date
    WHEN (((Reg.Date)=#6/16/2014#)) THEN Reg.Date1 = #6/16/2014#
END
```

Please help !!! 
MS ACCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you tagged your post with both "MySQL" and "SQL-Server", but then referenced MS Access in the text. Which database system are you, in fact, using? How you implement something like this very much depends on the DB system, as there is no common support for it in the SQL standard. That said:

1. If you are using MS Access, then you want a "crosstab" query (just Google it; plenty of how-to articles already out there)
2. If you are using SQL Server, then you want a "pivot" query (again, just Google)
3. If you are using MySQL, then AFAIK you have to roll your own using an approach something like the one outlined here: http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-a-table-in-mysql/

Good luck!